# what does "Encountered: <EOF> after : "" " mean using pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

I am a beginner on Hadoop and Pig. I examined the example proved in cloudera virtual image, and modefied it to count Top 5 frequent words:

```
Lines = LOAD '/user/hue/pig/examples/data/midsummer.txt' as (line:CHARARRAY);
Words = FOREACH Lines GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) AS word;
Groups = GROUP Words BY word;
Counts = FOREACH Groups GENERATE group, COUNT(Words);
Results = ORDER Words BY Counts DESC;
Top5 = LIMIT Results 5;
STORE Top5 INTO /user/hue/pig/examples/data/summertop5Hi
```

However, when I run this script, I got this message error:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt  - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Lexical error at line 8, column 0.  Encountered: <EOF> after : ""
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fix three issues in your code to make it work.
 1.`STORE stmt` is not properly ended with `semicolon`.
    2.`STORE stmt` output file is not properly enclosed with `single quotes`.
    3. Need slight modification in `Counts and Results` stmt logic.

**Modified Script:**

```
Lines = LOAD '/user/hue/pig/examples/data/midsummer.txt' as (line:CHARARRAY);
Words = FOREACH Lines GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(line)) AS word;
Groups = GROUP Words BY word;
Counts = FOREACH Groups GENERATE group, COUNT(Words) AS cnt;
Results = ORDER  Counts BY cnt DESC;
Top5 = LIMIT Results 5;
STORE Top5 INTO '/user/hue/pig/examples/data/summertop5';
```

If you face any issues in the script, let me know.